# Cargar carpeta local con archivos a Sharepoint utilizando Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

Espero me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente. El código que tengo abajo, me funciona para cargar un archivo desde mi equipo local a sharepoint, pero no sé como cargar toda una carpeta con archivos dentro a una carpeta de sharepoint. La información en español e inglés que he encontrado en internet está relacionada con la carga de archivos individuales, pero no de toda una carpeta con archivos dentro. Alguien tiene conocimiento de cómo se puede hacer esto?. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
import requests
from shareplum import Office365

# Set Login Info
username = 'miusuario@dominio.com'
password = 'micontraseña*'
site_name = 'misitio'
base_path = 'https://mitenant.sharepoint.com'
doc_library = f'Documentos%20compartidos'

nested_folder = f'Documentos%20compartidos/archivos'
file_name = "miarchivo.png" # mi archivo en mi equipo local

# Obtain auth cookie
authcookie = Office365(base_path, username=username, password=password).GetCookies()
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies = authcookie
session.headers.update({'user-agent': 'python_bite/v1'})
session.headers.update({'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'})

session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': 'FormDigestValue'})
response = session.post(url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + "')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)",
                         data="")
session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': response.headers['X-RequestDigest']})

# Upload file
with open(file_name, 'rb') as file_input:
    try:
        response = session.post(
            url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + f"/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + nested_folder + "')/Files/add(url='"
            + file_name + "',overwrite=true)",

            data=file_input)
        print("response: ", response.status_code) #it returns 200
        if response.status_code == '200':
            print("File uploaded successfully")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Something went wrong: " + str(err))

print('File Uploaded Successfully')
```